# jQuery Selectable - one function by multiple List

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

I've got two (or more) ordered list from the jQuery-type "selectable" with multiple items, like this:

```
<ol id="selectable" class="0">
   <li class="ui-widget-content">
      <div>
        <img src="..."></br>
        <span>Item 1 - Row 1</span>
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-widget-content">
      <div>
        <img src="..."></br>
        <span>Item 2 - Row 1</span>
      </div>
   </li>
</ol>
<ol id="selectable" class="1">
   <li class="ui-widget-content">
      <div>
        <img src="..."></br>
        <span>Item 1 - Row 2</span>
      </div>
   </li>
   ...
</ol>
```

Now if got two function to query the index of the selected "selectable"

```
$( "#selectable.0" ).selectable({
filter: "li",
selecting: function (event, ui) {
  $(event.target).children('.ui-selecting').not(':first').removeClass('ui-selecting');
  row = event.target.className[0]},
  stop: function() {
    var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
    $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
      index = $( "#selectable.0 li" ).index( this );
      values[row] = String(index)
    });
  }
});

$( "#selectable.1" ).selectable({
filter: "li",
selecting: function (event, ui) {
  $(event.target).children('.ui-selecting').not(':first').removeClass('ui-selecting');
  row = event.target.className[0]},
  stop: function() {
    var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
    $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
      index = $( "#selectable.1 li" ).index( this );
      values[row] = String(index)

    });
  }
});
```

This code is very redundant, and I want to merge this two function into one, which can decide which list selected and also gives me back the index of the selected item. Important is also that I don't want the index of **all** items

Comment: you should not have the same ID for multiple elements on the same page. If you want to do this, change the ID to CLASS - yes you can have multiple classes per element

Comment: At first glance, I saw the mistake mentioned by Adjit above. you should fix that first (Think as an ID as something unique: only one)

Comment: Thx, changing the ID to CLASS and visa versa works perfect!